# How to find if a string contains a specific integer php

Tags: php, string

I have a variable that outputs as  0 type int
I have another string that outputs as 0,1,2.

I am trying to find out if the string contains that very integer, both of these are dynamic values and being fetched from database.

I have tried -

```
if (strpos($string, $int) !== false) {
            echo 'true';
        }
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use type conversion:

```
if (strpos($string, (string) $int) !== false)
            echo 'true';
```